Deleting Application Package using BatchClient API
I have a requirement to delete an Azure Batch Application package from our .Net background service. I am using BatchClient for various pool and job operations. It seems the ApplicationOperations Class does not have API to delete an application package. Whats the recommended way to delete an application from an application runtime?
[Edit]
I have come across the Application Delete Rest API and an Az powershell API but they are not feasible for my requirement as (per my understanding) they would require an azure credential (similar to what az login would return) with the user having authorization to perform delete.
Currently we are using BatchClient initialized with BatchSharedKeyCredentials and would have preferred to use it to delete a Batch Applicaiton Package. something like
var client = BatchClient.Open(cred);
client.ApplicationOperations.DeleteApplication(appId, appVersion); //supposed API
The other way could be using System / User assigned managed identities with BatchApplicationPackageResource.DeleteAsync Method  as suggested by @rickvdbosch but Ideally we would want to be consistent and use the same BatchClient for all Batch operations

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! In its current form, your question is not a great fit for SO. For instance: why are the Application Delete Rest API and the AZ PowerShell API not feasible for your requirement? Please refer to [ask].

@rickvdbosch thanks for the comment. I have edited my question and tried to add a little more detail. I hope this adds more context. I am not sure why the BatchClient wouldnt support deleting applications, is there any reason?

You can implement this using the BatchApplicationPackageResource.DeleteAsync Method in the Azure.ResourceManager.Batch package.
The code would look something like this (NOT TESTED):
    var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
    var subscription = client.GetSubscriptionResource(new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{subId}"));
    var batchAccount = await subscription.GetBatchAccountAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName);
    var application = await batchAccount.GetBatchApplicationAsync(applId);
    await application.GetBatchApplicationPackage(version).DeleteAsync();

